# Understanding the meaning of random when working with measures repeated at time=1,2,3,4

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, computational-statistics

This stems from a recent exercise in an undergrad course, where we measured average resting heart rate(fH), and fH while holding breath of durations between 0-20s,20-40s,40-60s, etc.

Not only could some participants not hold their breath longer than the 1-20s mark, but the software we were using introduced enough trouble to cause the dropping of some measurements (e.g. if the 20-40s fH was obviously unattainable, it was dropped and the 0-20s measure was kept.

Can ANOVA be used to analyze this data? A t-test? I ask because the idea of random has suddenly confused me with repeated subjects- if we will use any statistical test, must we compare, say, the first four time marks, for those subjects who have data for all four, or is it feasible to compare all subjects, for all time marks?

I would really love some insight on the matter- and I would happily supply the data (75 participants, five time marks) if anyone should need further insight.

They used Excel for most of their work, I use R (because R is where it's at, colloquially speaking).

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've thus far learned that "repeated measures ANOVA" which is "unbalanced" should soothe my requirements out. Any advice on how to go about it in the right fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let us suppose that the missing values are caused by some mechanism unrelated to the ability to perform the task. This might be if they did not show up to the lab that day because their transport broke down or their cat died or for a reason related to the characteristics of the people but not what they would have obtained. In that case you can use a mixed effects model which if you use R is available in the `nlme` package which you should already have installed. You may like to look for material on missingness mechanisms: missing completely at random, missing at random (MCAR, MAR).

However your missing values are indeed related to the value that they would have obtained if the task had gone ahead. (Missing not at random, informative missing). You could group people by how far they could get with the task and then use that as a factor in the analysis and use it to form interactions with the variables you are interested in to see how ability to proceed interacts with (say) change over time.